# Adding square brackets to character class in Java regex

Tags: java, regex, character, lines

I would like to read a content `String` from file lne by line, and in each line remove all caharcters that are not one of the following  `[ { } ]`
I wanted to used a method:

```
line = line.replaceAll("[^[({})]]","");
```

but the problem is that char `[` and `]` means in regex syntax something else.
How to deal with it?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, the regex character classes can have unions and intersections, thus, `[` and `]` must be escaped inside if you want them to be treated as literal symbols. And since `\` can be used to define escape sequences, it should be doubled to denote a literal regex-escaping `\`.

Use

```
line = line.replaceAll("[^\\[({})\\]]","");
                          ^^     ^^
```